# Complex Number multiplied with Scalar

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I've got a formular `-j(a*x + b*x)` where j is a complex number.

When I'm not mistaken, `-j` gets defined as `std::complex<double> j(0,-1)`. All right, let's say `(a*x + b*y) = 5`. I've read on SO, it will be translated to `std::complex<double> scalarCmplx(5,0)`.

When multiplying `j*scalarCmplx` this will translate to:

```
real = j.real * scalarCmplx.real = 0 * 5 = 0
imag = j.imag * scalarCmplx.imag = -1 * 0 = 0
```

Thus, in my understanding, the result will be `0` always.
Do I miss something?

Comment: Complex multiplication doesn't work like that, just look up the definition again and it should be clear.

Comment: Oh, did I confuse something? I've looked up Krantz99, am I right if (-j)*5 would easily translate in `j.real*5, j.imag*5`? (@harold)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a misunderstanding of how complex numbers work, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in simple math where `s(a+b) = sa+sb`, the complex `-i` translates to `0-i`, thus `s*-i = s*0-s*i = -si`.